# DNS configuration validation

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, internal-dns

I am having issues migrating my current Active Directory objects to my new Domain using ADMT. I have gone to a lot of resources to resolve this issue and they seem to point to DNS. Is there a tool or command or something that can validate my DNS configuration is functioning correctly? The DNS server is a Win server 2000 and is the primary Domain Controller.

Comment: Are you migrating within the same forest, or to a different forest?

Comment: what error are you getting when using ADMT? You are migrating from Windows 2000 to which version? Cheers

Comment: migrating to 2k8 r2.

Comment: this would be an interforest migration.

Comment: thanks, what error are you getting?

Comment: Also check out the ADMT guide you should be using 3.1. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6D710919-1BA5-41CA-B2F3-C11BCB4857AF&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Men & Mice have a tool called DNS Expert that I've used in the past and was impressed by.

It's whole function is to hep you identify problems with your DNS infrastructure, and they have a specific module for AD DNS too.

The product page is [here](http://www.menandmice.com/solutions/modules/dnsmonitoring/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Since DNS is platform-independent at the protocol level, I wonder if you have a Unix/Linux box somewhere you can run commands on?

You're after "doc", which does DNS audits by wandering around the zone, looking at records.  It's somewhat old, and it won't *tell* you it's leaving a log in log.<zone>, but it works.  It assumes that you have dig, from bind9, which you probably will, on any modern Unix.  [ftp site](ftp://ftp.shub-internet.org/pub/shub/brad/dns/)

Another diagnosis tool is dnswalk, which is a sourceforge hosted project; since I can only post one hyperlink, I'll let you find that one.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say that I have a huge amount of experience with W2K AD domains, but if this was W2K3 then my first port of call would be the [`netdiag`](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1EA70814-7E6C-46E5-8C8C-3C439A732E9F) command. This will do some basic tests of your configuration including DNS.

I highly recommend using the `netdiag /q` command which reduced the level of output to only warnings and failures.

Comment: running the netdiag /q gives the following after the interface results and os Patches
<code>Global results:
    [WARNING] You don't have a single interface with the <00> 'WorkStation Servi
ce', <03> 'Messenger Service', <20> 'WINS' names defined.


DNS test . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Passed
    PASS - All the DNS entries for DC are registered on DNS server '192.168.0.5'
 and other DCs also have some of the names registered.

IP Security test . . . . . . . . . : Passed
</code>

Answer (score -5):

Does your new domain run WIndows Server 2008 R2? In that case you can use the built-in AD Best Practices Analyzer tool (find it under the AD role in Server Manager) to report on non-standard configuration.

Otherwise, you should go through ALL your DNS configuration, and try to draw it up on a piece of paper. Try to do nslookup's both ways, and put down your results on paper, the problem should materialize itself.. :) (some variant of "reverse-sudoku-solving".. :))

When you give up, you can call me and I *will* solve the issue for you, at $190/hour.. :)

Comment: First, the OP said he's working with W2K, the W2K8 AD BPA is not going to help him in the W2K source domain. Second, it's obvious that if he was able to go through DNS to find the problem on his own he wouldn't be posting his question here.